# Javascript: JSON 'for loop'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

The following Javascript displays in Safari but not Mobile Safari. Can anyone see any bugs?

```
$("#results").append(data);

var songdata = JSON.parse(data);

var i = 0;

for (i=0;i<=songdata.total;i++)
{
    alert(i);
    var songhtml = "<ul><li><img src=\"" + songdata.data[i].artwork + "\" /></li><li>" + songdata.data[i].title + "</li><li>" + songdata.data[i].artist + "</li><li>" + songdata.data[i].length + "</li><li>" + songdata.data[i].listen + "</li></ul>";
    $("#results").append(songhtml);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you appending `data` before parsing?

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Is none of it being executed?  Is the src attribute in the img tags blank?  Does it fail after the first pass in the for loop?  Please be a little more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.parse is not official Javascript, its not supported in all browsers. That could be your problem, but I don't have mobile safari to test it on.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Download this file and

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/js/JSON2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I've done some testing and that's the case. What are the alternatives to this function?

Comment: Thank you very much. Working a treat!

Answer (score 1):

I have to second MindStalkers comment. Id bet its your use of the non cross browser `JSON.parse`. In addition to that your loop structure looks suspicious - plus it doesnt make much sense to me to why you are using a standard loop instead of `jQuery.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `for (i=0;i<=songdata.total;i++)` looks suspicious to me. You're starting with zero, but continuing equal to or greater than `total`, so you're going to loop `total` **+ 1** times. (I take it this isn't a JavaScript/JSON array, as you're using `total` rather than `length`.)

If `total` tells you how many entries there are, and if the entries start at `0`, then use just `<`. If the entries start at `1`, do that. :-) But if you reference an invalid `songdata[i]`, then `songdata[i].artwork` will fail because `songdata[i]` will be undefined.